# Not able to export function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have defined a function service in one of the file

```
import Category from '../models/Category.js';

export const AllCategories = () => {
        console.log('hit');
        const cursor =  Category.find({});
        console.log(cursor);
        return cursor
}


export default {AllCategories}
```

I am importing this in the controller file

```
import express from 'express';
import categoryService from '../services/categories.js'
const router = express.Router();

export const getCategories = async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const categoriesInfo = categoryService.AllCategories
        res.status(200).json(categoriesInfo)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export default router;
```

But the issue is that AllCategories is not getting run, what is wrong here

I also tried adding async/await

```
import Category from '../models/Category.js';

export const AllCategories = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("hit");
        const cursor =  await Category.find({});
        console.log(cursor);
        return cursor
    } catch (error) {
       return error 
    }
}


export default {AllCategories}
```

But still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the function, this saves it in the variable `categoriesInfo`:

```
const categoriesInfo = categoryService.AllCategories
```

To get its return value:

```
const categoriesInfo = await categoryService.AllCategories();
```

Note: I think you need to make it `async` if you're doing a db transaction so keep the second version and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `ES module or ESM` syntax by default in node.js. You either have to use `CommonJS` syntax or you have to do 1 of the following.

1. Change the file extension from `.js` to `.mjs`
2. Add to the nearest `package.json` file a field called `type` with a value of `module`